# Mat-Paginator not working on api based mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm implementing a mat-table that retrieve information from an API.

The mat-table is showing data as expected.

The mat-paginator is not working.

Below the code I'm using:

Component:

```
import {DataService} from '../../services/data.service';
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.css'],

})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
  projects: any;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  displayedColumns: any;
  length: number;
  pageSize: number=1;
  pageSizeOptions = [1, 5, 10, 50];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { 

  }



  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Retrieving projects");
    this.getProjects().then(
      projects => {
        console.log("Projects retrieved", projects);
        this.projects=projects;
        this.dataSource = this.projects;
        console.log(this.dataSource);
        this.displayedColumns = [
          'prj_id',
          'title',
          'priority_id'
        ];
        this.length=this.projects.length;


      }
    ).catch(function (data){
      console.log("Rejected", data);
    });

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }


  getProjects(){
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.dataService.getProjects().subscribe(
        projects => {
          resolve(projects);
        },
        error => {
          console.log("error retrieving projects");
          reject("error retrieving projects");
        }
      )
    });
    return promise;
  }

}

export interface Projects {
  prj_id: string;
  title: string;
  priority_id: number;
}
```

HTML VIEW:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >


    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" ><mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Project</button>

</div>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">

  <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100">
      <mat-card>
          <mat-card-content> 
              <mat-card-title backgroundColor="primary">Projects</mat-card-title>
              <div class="table-rasponsive">
                  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

                  <!-- Position Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="prj_id">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.prj_id}} </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>

                  <!-- Name Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> TITLE </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>

                   <!-- Name Column -->
                   <ng-container matColumnDef="priority_id">
                      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> PRIORITY </mat-header-cell>
                      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.priority_id}} </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>



                  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
                </mat-table>

                <mat-paginator  #paginator
                                [length]="length"
                                [pageSize]="pageSize"
                                [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions">
                </mat-paginator>
              </div>    
          </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**if you are fetching data from API, then the task is async** means it will call the next steps even without completing API request, there is no data in the data source if you apply paginator without data definitely paginator won't work. if you console.log(this.paginator.paginator) you will get undefined, means your data source is not initialized, so you are not able to apply paginator to the data source

**To make it work, always assign data and paginator respectively after completing API requests.**

```
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    
    ngOnInit(){
    yourService.getData().subscribe(
        (data)=>{
           this.datasource.data = data;
           this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                },
        (error)=>{}
       );
    }
```

// note always keep `<mat-paginator> after <mat-table>`

Comment: thanks, this is the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 9):

After having a lot of headaches I did figure out the problem.
Check this line

```
this.dataSource = this.projects;
```

and change it with

```
this.dataSource.data = this.projects;
```

It should solve your problem. Also, *ngAfterViewInit* is ok, don't change it.

Comment: Didn't work on Angular 7. Still the same. I wonder what is causing the problem.

Comment: Maybe your case is different. This case should work on Angular 7.

Comment: you deserve a medal even now in 2023!!!! you saved me!!!

Answer (score 4):

use the below line

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.projects);
```

if paginator is still not working, for Dynamically loaded table data use `read` argument for MatPaginator

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {read: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

this will do the job.

Comment: This did work !!! Thanks a-lot, It means we have to tell pagination that we are using dynamic data ?

Answer (score 2):

Please try to initialize the MATPAGINATOR and MATSORT as follows and this worked for me.

```
public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
@ViewChild(MatSort) matSort: MatSort;

private paginator: MatPaginator;
private sort: any;

@ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  @ViewChild(MatSort) set content(content: ElementRef) {
    this.sort = content;
    if (this.sort) {
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
  }

  setDataSourceAttributes() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

Above code checks for the paginator and sort variables and will gets set when they are undefined.
Also no need to add #paginator in your HTML file.

Thanks and Regards,
Kishore Kumar. K

Comment: Best solution that I have found on Stackoverflow! Thanks a lot.

Comment: but their is a problem that .. with this approach the total length of paginator is being overriden with result values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Remove the code from ngAfterViewInit();

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

and add it in ngOnInit();

Answer (score 0):

Try this and remove code from ngAfterInit()

```
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
          this.paginator = mp;
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
   }
```