# Pagination is disabled when loading mat table data dynamically from API

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material, angular16

I am trying to populate mat-table via dynamic data from an API.
Data is getting populated but pagenation part is unresponsive.
I tried solutions provided in below links on Stackoverflow, non of them worked. I am using Angular 16 and angular material 16.2.10

[Solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532308/mat-paginator-not-working-on-api-based-mat-table)

[Solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532308/mat-paginator-not-working-on-api-based-mat-table)

[Solution3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550504/matpaginator-not-working-in-dynamically-generated-table)

[Solution4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117535/angular-material-mat-paginator-navigation-is-disabled)

[Solution5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517107/angular-mat-table-pagination-not-working-entire-data-is-loaded-on-first-page-of)

PFB my code:
**Component.ts:**

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-api',
  templateUrl: './test-api.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-api.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule]
})
export class TestAPIComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'city', 'latitude'];
  public getJsonValue: any;
  public dataSource: any = [];
//code for pagination: tried all solutions from stackoverflow , none worked
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  //@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {read: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  
  /*@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false})
  set paginator(value: MatPaginator) {
    this.dataSource.paginator = value;
  } */

  /*@ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}*/
  
  constructor(private http : HttpClient){

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMethod();
    //this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  public getMethod(){
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe((data) => {
      console.table(data);
      console.log(this.paginator);
      this.getJsonValue = data;
      this.dataSource = data;
      //tried below code from stackoverflow but didn't work and commented ngAfterViewInit code
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
    
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   //this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }  
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<p>test-api works!</p>
<H1>Test API</H1>
<!--p>{{getJsonValue | json}}</p-->

<h1>Test API: Dynamic</h1>
<p>dynamic-table works!</p>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  
      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> email </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <!-- Symbol Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="city">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> city </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address.city}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Symbol Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="latitude">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Latitude </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address.geo.lat}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
    [pageSize]="5"
                   showFirstLastButtons
                   aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

Current Table UI with disabled pagination:
[image]

Comment: A mat-paginator can be use when the dataSource **is** a [MatTableDataSource](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination) not a simple array. You should use in your subscribe function: `datasource=MatTableDataSource(data)`. Well, really you can use a matPaginator in "standalone way" and use [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe), like e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73383711/how-to-implement-pagination-for-dynamic-inner-datasource-inside-other-mat-table/73384208#73384208) -but you loose the posibility of, e.g. sort or filter-

Comment: @Eliseo can you please provide syntax for adding MatTableDataSource(data) I am getting errors. I am very new to Angular.

Comment: I forgot the "this", I add an answer to see the whole question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your variable as MatTableDataSource

```
dataSource!:MatTableDataSource<any>
```

When you get it

```
public getMethod(){
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe((data:any[]) => {
      //you create a MatTableDataSource
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      //you asig the paginator
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
    
  }
```

NOTE: You should use a service to get the data (it's considered "good practice" instead of use in your component the httpClient, e.g.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  //simply return an observable
  getData():Observable<any[]> { //<--indicate the return of the function
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users') //<--indicate in get the type
  }
}
```

In your component

```
  constructor(private dataService:DataService){}

  //and use

    public getMethod(){
        this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data:any[]) => {
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        });
        
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the details answer but I am getting compilation error in getMethod() at (data:any[])  ::  No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer<Object>> | ((value: Object) => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(data: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Observer<Object>> | ((value: Object) => void) | undefined'.
      Type '(data: any[]) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: Object) => void'.
        Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.

Comment: sorry, Angular 16 is each time more stricte. I update the code and make a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5kzakz?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter). It's indicate in service the type of the get and the return function in getData

Comment: It worked !! Thanks a lot.